How to verify file properties on GitHub?
I have a file in a private GitHub repository that contains several properties, such as 'status=operational'. How can I verify that the 'status' property is correctly set to 'operational'?
Is there an API or library available that can read and verify the content of a file stored in a GitHub repository?

I guess you are referring to getting the content of a file hosted on GitHub, it depends if this repository is private or public.

Get the file via git or GitHub's API, read it, check the content. Which part of that specifically are you having a problem with?

Additionally, please note that the repository in question is private. How does this affect the ability to read and verify the content of the file, and are there any specific considerations or tools required for accessing files in a private GitHub repository?

That just means you'll need to authenticate with either the git or GitHub API, but again it's unclear where precisely you're stuck. Maybe write a GitHub Actions workflow, then checking out the latest commit is trivial and you can run whatever code you want.

For a private repository try this
private static readonly string SERVER_URL = $"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/{GITHUB_OWNER}/{GITHUB_REPO}/main/";

private static string GetFileContentFromGitHub(string fileName)
{
    var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(SERVER_URL + fileName);
    webRequest.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, "token " + GITHUB_TOKEN);
    webRequest.Method = "GET";

    using (var response = webRequest.GetResponse())
    {
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8)) 
        {
            return reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
    
}

You can create a GitHub token under the developer settings.
